# how to handle there is not installed twitter on your device exception when we are trying to login with twitter in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying o create a flutter application. and I have success working with login with Facebook and Twitter. there is a problem while I'm trying to login with Twitter. My device has not been installed on the twitter application and I'm facing the problem for null value assign. Have anyone maid a solution for the issue.

```
E/flutter (20681): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'token' was called on null.
E/flutter (20681): Receiver: null
E/flutter (20681): Tried calling: token
E/flutter (20681): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter (20681): #1      _LoginScreenState._loginWithTwitter (package:c2c_app/src/screens/Account/Login/login_page.dart:104:39)
E/flutter (20681): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20681): #2      _LoginScreenState._buildLoginWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:c2c_app/src/screens/Account/Login/login_page.dart:581:40)
E/flutter (20681): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
E/flutter (20681): #4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
E/flutter (20681): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (20681): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
E/flutter (20681): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
E/flutter (20681): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:236:7)
E/flutter (20681): #9      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter (20681): #10     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:222:20)
E/flutter (20681): #11     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter (20681): #12     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (20681): #13     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (20681): #14     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (20681): #15     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
E/flutter (20681): #16     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (20681): #17     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter (20681): #18     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273:10)
E/flutter (20681): #19     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:5)
E/flutter (20681):
```

Comment: are you using any package

Comment: Can you show your code so that we can have an idea about the issue?

Answer (score 0):

you need to just put try and catch block inside twitter login code